# What's a good website for asking questions about Jewish life and learning and getting crowd-sourced answers?

Tags: product-recommendation, internet

What's a good website for asking questions about Jewish life and learning and getting crowd-sourced answers?

Comment: CHABAD.ORG is a very knowledgeable and community interactive site. The Rabbis there are very accommodating and helpful, plus they have extensive knowledge of all things Jewish.

Comment: A belated welcome to Mi Yodeya and thank you for the interesting question! You may be interested in [these questions](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/2/isaac-moses?tab=questions&sort=votes) as well. I look forward to seeing you around :)

Comment: @DoubleAA, thank you so much for the warm welcome. You know, if that's how people act around here, I think I will stick around. Have you got anything about numbers?

Comment: Indeed we do! You should see our special [Mi Yodeya series](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series?sort=newest&pageSize=50) which is all about numbers in Judaism. It gets questions about new numbers whenever the manager of the series happens to remember about it (roughly).

Comment: Crowd sourced rather than Halacha sourced? Opinions no matter how many diferent people do not really apply. Answers to questions about Judaism need to be sourced in the Torah. *Crowd sourcing* is not really proper.

Comment: @sabbahillel For Halacha questions (which is not all this question asks about), the crowd is useful for *discovering* and *verifying* what Halacha says, not for making it up.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You might want to check out [mi.yodeya.com](http://mi.yodeya.com), the Judaism site on the [StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com/) network. They allow questions and even answers from anyone, but the community editing and voting process, along with the great crowd of people who tend to hand out there tends to result in excellent, well-sourced answers being posted fairly quickly for most questions.

*Full disclosure: I founded [mi.yodeya](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1/where-did-all-these-posts-come-from) and am a member of Mi Yodeya.*

Answer (score 5):

[Judaism.codidact.com](https://judaism.codidact.com/) is a question-and-answer site similar in many respects to this one but with its own content, an open-source platform, and non-profit ownership, [responsive to its community](https://cellio.medium.com/building-codidact-communities-1b9e0895373e).

Answer (score 4):

There is an email list called Mail Jewish which discusses matters of this nature.

Send submissions/responses for mail.jewish to:

mj@mj.bu.edu

The archive site is http://www.ottmall.com/mj_ht_arch/

This is a listserv which has been in existence since the before the beginning of the internet (it goes back to the original Bell Labs days) and has dealt with all issues involving Judaism. It is a moderated list, so it is recommended that you look through the archives to see what types of things are discussed.

I would consider it as a crowd sourcing site and the archives are available as well. [Mail Jewish Torah and Halacha Home Page](http://www.shamash.org/mail-jewish/) Each volume is pointed to by [Mail-Jewish Digest Hypertext Edition](http://www.ottmall.com/mj_ht_arch/) and [Mail Jewish Volumes Archives](http://www.shamash.org/mail-jewish/mjvols.html)

Comment: Also Areivim (spelling?).

Answer (score 4):

I have frequently seen such questions posted to general-purpose social media networks like [Facebook](http://facebook.com), [Twitter](http://twitter.com), and [Reddit](http://reddit.com) (particularly the [Jewish corner](http://reddit.com/r/judaism) thereof). These sites don't have the same controls for quality that Mi Yodeya does, but they can often draw large numbers of people to address a question, relatively quickly, with varying degrees of seriousness and usefulness.

Comment: Since the quality of answers should be judged without regard to [other answers](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2/5323) on the question.....have [a hat](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/major-award) ;-)

Comment: @Shokhet, I'm not sure what hat you think you just gave me. Thanks for the upvote, though.

Comment: I edited my comment with a link.

Comment: Oh, the bounty on this question was awarded already :P

Answer (score 1):

There is **Quora.com** in which you can search for the subject you are interested in or follow the tags [Jewish Theology and Philosophy](https://www.quora.com/topic/Jewish-Theology-and-Philosophy/top_questions) and [Judaism](https://www.quora.com/topic/Judaism/top_questions) to ask questions and getting answers. Many of them are too broad for the scope of these topics, but some q&a are good though.