# Is there any torah study community that allows Non - Jews?

Tags: gentiles, torah-study

I am not a Jew, or religious in any manner, but Judaism interests me, since I study religions. It is very hard to study on my own, so I have tried to find a study partner or teacher many times, on sites like torahstudypartners, and a local synagogue, but have been denied because I am not Jewish.

So, is there any community that would help me learn, even though I am not Jewish?

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2

Comment: sorta related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23042/759 and qs linked from there

Comment: Hmmm ... I see Chaba"dnicks occasinally pass out "B'nai Noach" brochures and cards at Atlantic Ave. subway station in Brooklyn. Don't they offer classes or have something online for them?

Comment: It really depends on what community. There are topics geared for non-Jews, like the noahide laws. If there's Chabad in your area, contact them and ask.

Comment: Yes. Find a Chabad house in your area and ask them to study the laws of the children of Noah. That is the usual starting point for all non-Jews.

Comment: contact rabbi bryant and ask him for bnei noach study group https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dn4sy72MjEE

Answer (score 2):

> ...By the same regard, Moses was commanded by the Almighty to compel all the inhabitants of the world to accept the commandments given to Noah's descendants... - *Mishneh Torah, Hilchot Melachim 8:10*

A Rabbi has an obligation to teach bnei Noach(children of Noah) the sheva mitzvot(seven laws of the children of Noah). Quote that to any Torah observant Rabbi and make an appointment to learn with him. If you physically cannot find one, there are plenty of classes to learn from online.

Comment: Does that apply if the Ben Noach in question isn't interested in following the laws about which he is learning?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I'd imagine it depends if it's in Eretz Yisrael or not. I would say it's at least incumbent at all times to teach them in some way.

Comment: perhaps this command applied only to Moses

Comment: how do you know this was not a one time mitzva specifically to moses?

Answer (score 2):

Not many Jews know this but we have an obligation to teach non-Jews the Torah relevant to them.

R Cary Friedman writes ([Hakirah](http://www.hakirah.org/) vol 24, p. 163) that

> Tosfot (Chagigah 13a d.h. ain mosrin) discusses our obligation to
>   provide the *umot ha-olam* (non Jewish nations) with the Torah they need
>   to animate their observance of the *sheva mitzvot bnei Noah*.
>   Instructing them in the universal mitzvos is not merely *reshus*,
>   optional, but rather a *chiyuv*, a requirement.

Some groups within Judaism, e.g., Chabad, have taken on themselves to provide education to that effect.

You could start online, e.g., [here](http://www.jewishidaho.com/templates/articlecco_cdo/aid/1415394/jewish/Judaism-for-non-Jews.htm), [here](https://www.chabad.org/search/keyword_cdo/kid/2123/jewish/Noahide-Laws-The-Seven.htm) or [here](https://www.chabad.org/multimedia/media_cdo/aid/466119/jewish/The-Seven-Noahide-Laws.htm). Or read a book such as [The Path of the Righteous Gentile: An Introduction to the Seven Laws of the Children of Noah](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/087306433X). Or see [here](http://www.aish.com/atr/Seven_Laws_of_Noah.html) more resources from Aish and [here](https://www.chabad.org/multimedia/media_cdo/aid/466119/jewish/The-Seven-Noahide-Laws.htm) for Brit Olam, the Noahide World Center. Finally you could contact your [nearest Chabad center](https://www.chabad.org/centers/default_cdo/jewish/Chabad-Centers-and-Synagogue-Directory.htm) and ask if they can help.

Answer (score 1):

One-on-one study is inherently resource-intensive, and I'm not surprised that sites that offer this service restrict it to Jews.  If they offered their services to everybody then they'd have to pay attention to avoid matching non-Jews up with each other (at which point you're more likely to get Christian misinterpretations than torah study).  And some of the people they're matching want to be matched with Jews for the (mutual) merit of torah study, which is an obligation for Jews but not for gentiles.

You are more likely to be successful if you look for *classes* or *study groups*.  My synagogue has three different weekly text-study groups (two torah, one Tanakh) that people can drop into at any time; this isn't unusual.  Nobody checks backgrounds; if people want to show up and learn, they show up and learn.  I know we've had non-Jews show up at times.  In cities with decent-sized Jewish communities, and/or Chabad, there are public classes of various sorts.  Look for opportunities like these, instead of for one-on-one study.

One caveat: a baseline assumption of Jewish study is *Judaism*.  There are other interpretations of our texts out there in the world, ranging from mistaken to fraudulent, and we've collectively been evangelized and attacked by some of these groups rather a lot.  *You* didn't do that, of course; I'm just explaining background to say this: it's ok to ask questions (we love questions!), but try to ask them with some humility and from within the frame of Judaism as best you understand it, and if the leader seems to be trying to move on, let it go.  As you attend more you'll get a sense of the group and this will be easier; initially, it's probably better to focus on listening and learning.